# examples of inverse matrices both with combinatorial meaning?

Tags: combinatorics

The infinite lower triangular matrices of Stirling numbers of the first and second kind are matrix inverses. So are the infinite lower triangular matrices of the binomials and the signed binomials. What are some examples of other pairs, both with combinatorial meaning?